# Creating English-UK sites via Sharepoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate, regional-settings

I am trying to create a new SharePoint Site collection via the REST API and trying to have that site be created using the English - United Kingdom Language rather than English - United States

I thought that to make this change all I would need to do would be to enter the LCID for en-GB which is 2057 as shown below, however when I try to run this action it fails to create a site though the action is successful.

[image]

Is there a way to create an English -UK site rather than an English -US site via Rest or is there a subsequent request I can make to change the language/regional settings of the site after it has been created to get the end result.

Answer (score 0):

So far, SharePoint online does not support the creation of a site collection with the lcid value is 2057.

[Supported LCIDs by SharePoint](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/Supported-LCIDs-by-SharePoint)